# многопоточное рисование в апплете java

Tags: java, многопоточность, applet

Пишу многопоточный апплет на java для имитации движения бильярдных шаров на плоскости. В классе Main создаются объекты типа Ball (сами шары), которые являются наследниками Thread, и запускаются. Для шаров генерируются рандомные направление, скорость и цвет. При столкновении со стенкой шары отражаются. Скорость постепенно уменьшается до остановки. Для рисования создаю BufferedImage, в которую рисую шар, а перед каждой следующей перерисовкой очищаю зарисованную область с помощью setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear).
ПРОБЛЕМЫ:
1) Шары мигают.
2) Не всегда при следующей перерисовке шара, предыдущая перерисовка стирается.

Comment: аплеты уже не поддерживаются

Comment: Мигание можно исправить если использовать двойную буферизацию

Comment: а зачем многопоточность при рисовании?

Comment: Множество потоков работают с одним экземпляром Graphics2d, я думаю если к методу draw добавить модификатор synchronized то мигать перестанет.

Comment: @АлександрБерезовский  это не помогло

Comment: `synchronized` на `draw` не поможет, но идея правильная. Нужен общий для всех классов монитор, например завернуть все обращения к `g2d` внутри `draw` в `synchronized( Ball.class ) { .. }`.

Comment: @zRrr Это помогло решить вторую проблему. Мигание всё ещё осталось. (выложил исправленный код)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем рисовать из разных потоков?

Это как выстрел себе в ногу в начале забега.

В виду сложного устройства графической подсистемы в целом, крайне не рекомендую рисовать из разных потоков, не только в java.

Вы попадаете в ловушку неопределенностей, порождаемых конкурентным использованием графического контекста.

Чаще всего гафический контекст не потоко-безопасен, между вызовами функций настройки состояния графического конвейера и вызовом метода draw не в коем случае не должны вклиниваться другие потоки, со своими инструкциями.

Comment: Рисую из разных потоков, увы, не по своему желанию. Такое условие задачи

Comment: @Кирилл это где такие задачи?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста дословно условия Вашей задачи

Answer (score 1):

Кто сможет, простите меня за мою тупость, я действительно не совсем правильно понял условие.

Comment: Это далеко не тупость, просто у меня закрались подозрения что вы не правильно интерпретировали задачу, рисование во много потоков возможно, например при  использовании vulkan api, но это совсем другая история